# Prove relation between coefficients of power series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

> If $f(x)=\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}c_mx^m$ has positive radius of convergence and $e^{f(x)}=\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}d_mx^m$, show that $$nd_n=\sum_{i=1}^nic_id_{n-i}$$
>   *James Stewart Calculus*

My answer below, others welcome.

Comment: Doesn't this follow in a line or two if you differentiate the l.h.s. of the equation for $e^{f(x)}$ using the chain rule and the r.h.s. termwise?  (And use the assumption about the radius of convergence to justify termwise differentation and expansion of the product of power series resulting from the use of the chain rule.)

Comment: @RobArthan I'm not sure what you mean, consider posting an answer.

Comment: I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}c_mx^m$ has positive radius of convergence and $e^{f(x)}=\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}d_mx^m$, we have:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}e^{f(x)} = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}d_mx^m.
$$

Using the chain rule on the left of this equation and termwise differentiation on the right, this gives:

$$
\left(\frac{d}{dx}f(x)\right)e^{f(x)} = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}md_mx^{m-1}.
$$

Differentiating the power series for $f(x)$ termwise and using the equation for $e^{f(x)}$, the above is:

$$
\left(\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}mc_mx^{m-1}\right)\left(\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}d_mx^m \right)= \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}md_mx^{m-1}.
$$
Multiplying out the product on the left gives:
$$
\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{m}ic_id_{m-i}\right)x^{m-1}= \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}md_mx^{m-1}.
$$
Comparing the coefficients of $x^{n+1}$ gives the desired result:

$$nd_n=\sum_{i=1}^nic_id_{n-i}.$$

[Motivation: the appearance of $nd_n$ in the goal, strongly suggests that the power series $\sum d_nx^n$ has been differentiated. So see what happens if you differentiate both sides of the equation involving that power series.]

Comment: How does $$\left(\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}mc_mx^{m-1}\right)\left(\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}d_mx^m \right)=\sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{m}ic_id_{m-i}\right)x^{m-1}$$?

Comment: Byt the [Cauchy product[(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) (which just amounts to multiplying out and collecting together the terms of each degree).

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $c_n$ represents the taylor expansion of $f(x)$, so $c_n=\frac{f'^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ where $f'^{(n)}$ is the nth derivative of $f$. Likewise, $d_n=\frac{g'^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, where $g(x)=e^{f(x)}$. All $d_n=\frac{e^{f(0)}}{n!}k_n(0)$ for the value $k_n(0)$, where $k_n(0)=p(0)$ and $p(x)=\frac{g(x)'^{(n)}}{e^{f(x)}}=\frac{(e^{f(x)})'^{(n)}}{e^{f(x)}}$. Letting $k_n(x)=p(x)$ satisifies all the values for $k_n(0)$ and provides the useful identity

$$k_{n+1}(x)=f'(x)k_n+k_n'$$
Proof:$$k_n(x)=p(x)=\frac{(e^{f(x)})'^{(n)}}{e^{f(x)}} \implies
\\
e^{f(x)}k_n(x)=(e^{f(x)})'^{(n)}\implies
\\
f'(x)e^{f(x)}k_n(x)+e^{f(x)}k_n'(x)=(e^{f(x)})'^{(n+1)} \implies
\\
\frac{(e^{f(x)})'^{(n+1)}}{e^{f(x)}}=f'(x)k_n+k_n' \implies
\\
k_{n+1}(x)=f'(x)k_n+k_n'
$$

So $$nd_n=\sum_{i=1}^nic_id_{n-i} \\ \Longleftrightarrow n \frac{e^{f(0)}}{n!}k_n(0)=\sum_{i=1}^ni\frac{f'^{(i)}(0)}{i!}\frac{e^{f(0)}}{(n-i)!}k_{n-i}(0)\\ \Longleftrightarrow k_n(0)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\begin{array}{c}n-1\\ \Longleftrightarrow i-1\end{array}\right)f'^{(i)}(0)k_{n-i}(0)\\ \Longleftrightarrow k_{n+1}(0)=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i-1\end{array}\right)f'^{(i)}(0)k_{n+1-i}(0)$$

I will prove the last one and have proven the first. But first, I will prove by induction a helper theorem: $$k_n(x)'=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}(x)$$ Base case: $$k_1'(x)=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\ 1\end{array}\right)f''(x)k_0(x)$$ is true, as $k_0(x)=\frac{e^{f(x)}}{e^{f(x)}}=1$ and $k_1(x)=\frac{f'(x)e^{f(x)}}{e^{f(x)}}=f'(x)$.

Assuming the theorem is true for case $n$, we have

$$k_n'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}(x) 
\\
 =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)\left(\frac{k_{n-i+1}(x)-k_{n-i}'(x)}{f'(x)}\right)$$

Because $k_{p+1}(x)=k_p'(x)+f'(x)k_p(x) \implies k_p(x)=\frac{k_{p+1}(x)-k_{p}'(x)}{f'(x)}$. So

$$f'(x)k_n'(x)
=
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)\left(k_{n-i+1}(x)-k_{n-i}'(x)\right)
=
\\
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i+1}(x)- \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}'(x)
=
\\
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\left(\begin{array}{c}n+1\\ i\end{array}\right)-\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i-1\end{array}\right)\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i+1}(x)- \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}'(x)
= 
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n+1\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i+1}(x)-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i-1\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i+1}(x)- \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}'(x)
\\ 
\implies
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n+1\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i+1}(x)=
\\
 \sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}'(x)+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i-1\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i+1}(x)+f'(x)k_n'
 \implies \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}n+1\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n+1-i}(x)=
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}'(x)+
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i-1\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i+1}(x)+f'(x)k_n'(x)+f'^{(n+2)}(x)k_0(x)
=
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}'(x)+
\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+2)}(x)k_{n-i}(x)+f'(x)k_n'(x)+f'^{(n+2)}(x)k_0(x)
=
\\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}'(x)+
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+2)}(x)k_{n-i}(x)+f'(x)k_n'(x)+f''(x)k_n(x)
$$
$$ $$
Now look at the above. It's the derivative of $\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}(x)\right)+f'(x)k_n(x) = k_n'(x)+f'(x)k_n(x)$ by the induction hypothesis. But $k_n'(x)+f'(x)k_n(x)=k_{n+1}(x)$, so the expression must equal $k_{n+1}'(x)$ and the theorem is proven.

Now $$k_n'(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}(x)\\ \implies k_{n+1}(x)=k_n'(x)+f'(x)k_n(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i\end{array}\right)f'^{(i+1)}(x)k_{n-i}(x)+f'(x)k_n(x)\\=\sum_{i=2}^{n+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i-1\end{array}\right)f'^{(i)}(x)k_{n+1-i}(x)+f'(x)k_n(x)\\=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\ i-1\end{array}\right)f'^{(i)}(x)k_{n+1-i}(x)$$

QED.